# Java writing output AudioInputStream + AudioFormat set wFormat to FLOAT?

Tags: java, audio, file-io, encoding, floating-point

I've confirmed my program "works" with a variety of signed integer output formats. However, when I attempt to use 32-bit floating point, the output audio metadata indicates it to be 32-bit signed integer, and this results in broken playback.

Here's my audio format:

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_FLOAT,
                                          48000, // Hz sample rate
                                          32, // bits per sample
                                          2, // channels
                                          8, // bytes per frame
                                          48000, // Hz frame rate
                                          false), // not big-endian
```

This is sent to a processor function (which I've confirmed "works" using other output formats):

```
public void mixToFile(AudioFormat format,
                      String outputPath,
                      int totalFrames) throws Exception {

  ByteBuffer outputBytes = byteBufferOf(mix()); // the big show

  AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBytes.array()), outputFormat,
    totalFrames
  );

  AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(outputPath));
}
```

The result is **failure**; the file has metadata format 32-bit signed int, see:

```
Playing WAVE '/tmp/output.wav' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of [How to write wav file with 32-bit float data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062620/how-to-write-wav-file-with-32-bit-float-data)
 which I've dealt with before, manually setting the wFormat tag in the 'fmt' chunk to WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT (3) when writing a RIFF container.

**Is it possible to achieve this using `AudioSystem.write`, `AudioInputStream` and `AudioFormat`?**

Comment: "whats the deal with floating???" cant you satisfy yourself with integer??? and why do they need floating - sound is sound!!! ....Anyway I ran my rant - now is your time

Comment: :) funny that an integer value of 2,147,483,648 drops the bass no harder than a floating point value of 1.0.  Yet the floating point range from -1 to 1 does, it turns out, persist information about what happened in the air on the microphone during the recording significantly better for something (like science) with lots of "important" detail in the lower-volume range.