# Why is my DAW reading my sin wav as a square wav?

Tags: c, audio

I am trying to generate a sin wave as PCM data in a wav file, but when I read the data into a DAW, it comes out as square.

I've confirmed that the data is in fact a sin wave using excel. I've tried switching to different sample rates and bit depths/amplitude, but the result is the same. The wav file comes out correctly written in format since the DAWs can read it, but it just has the incorrect sample data. Relevant code:

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE 48000.0
#define BIT_DEPTH 32
#define FREQUENCY 440.0 // A4 
#define NUM_CHANNELS 1
#define AMPLITUDE 1.0

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

...
// header info

 wav_header header =
    {
        {'R','I','F','F'},
        36 + sampleCount * sizeof(float),
        {'W','A','V','E'},
        {'f','m','t',' '},
        16,
        1,
        NUM_CHANNELS,
        SAMPLE_RATE,
        SAMPLE_RATE * NUM_CHANNELS * BIT_DEPTH / 8,
        NUM_CHANNELS * BIT_DEPTH / 8,
        BIT_DEPTH,
        {'d','a','t','a'},
        sampleCount * sizeof(float)
    };

...

// Loop that writes the data. "generated" is the File
for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    {
        float t = (float)i / SAMPLE_RATE; // unit circle division
        //float sample = (float)(AMPLITUDE * sin(2 * M_PI * FREQUENCY * t));
        float x_sample = sinf(2 * M_PI * FREQUENCY * t);
        fwrite(&x_sample, sizeof(float), 1, generated);
    }
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: According to this: https://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html your format code is wrong: `1` means PCM data, but it looks like you are writing floats - try to change it to `3` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062620/how-to-write-wav-file-with-32-bit-float-data plus Mcgil keeps a mirror of the original memo https://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Docs/rfc2361.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a tone using the C89 WAV library.

https://github.com/jocic/c89-wav

```
uint32_t i;
float    j;

///////////////////////

uint32_t sample_rate   = 44100;
uint32_t duration      = 2;
uint32_t total_samples = sample_rate * duration;

///////////////////////

WAV_FILE  file;
WAV_PCM16 sample;

///////////////////////

file = wav_open("test.wav", WAV_NEW);

wav_set_defaults(&file, 1);

for (i = 0, j = 0; i < total_samples; i++, j+=0.1F) {
    sample = sin(j) * WAV_PCM16_MAX;
    wav_push_sample(&file, &sample, NULL);
}

wav_close(&file);
```

For more advanced stuff, here are the examples.

https://github.com/jocic/c89-wav/tree/main/examples